# What does the metal property do in THREE.JS?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've seen code examples with `metal: true` property on materials. The documentation is set to "todo." I've also tried toggling the bool value in code and Chrome DevTools and have not noticed a difference.

Does anyone know what the property does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `metal` flag, when set to `true` in `MeshPhongMaterial`, causes the material to reflect direct light the way a metallic material does.

In particular, the specular highlight is tinted by the diffuse color of the material.

Actually, I do not believe this is currently implemented correctly, and it is something that needs to be looked at again. This is why setting the flag often does not appear to make a visual difference.

three.js r.62

Comment: Thank you. I see the difference now that I knew what to look for. Though if the material is white, there is no difference.

Comment: Ideally it would switch on anisotropic specular shading... :)